# Android - Send HTTP Request with AsyncTask on Button Click | Problems with delegate

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, delegates

i am about to write a small application. On button click i send a http request in a custom async task class. I want to write this value in a EditText field and in a ListView as item. My problem now is that i want to return the value of the request to the main thread to process it further. I searched around and found a method with an interface. This is my asynctask class:

```
    public class Request extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;
    private MainActivity mAct;
    public Request(MainActivity mainActivity){
        this.mAct = mainActivity;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url){
        String returnString = "";
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url[0]);
            final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            byte[] content = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            String strContent = "";
            while((bytesRead = bis.read(content)) != -1){
                strContent += new String(content,0,bytesRead);
            }
            returnString = strContent;
        } catch (Exception e){

        } finally {
            return returnString;
        }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSendMessage);
    final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.treeView);
    final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtReqID);

    final MainActivity ma = this;
    final ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrList);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            String t = new String("http://myhttprequest");
            Request r = new Request(ma);
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                r.delegate = this;
            }

            editText.setText(returnValue);
            lv.setAdapter(arrAdapter);
            arrList.add(returnValue);
            arrAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
public interface AsyncResponse{
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

The problem is that i have to declare every variable as final because i acces them within a function. I don't feel very happy with my code now and i also have no idea how i can make this work. Any help is very much appreciated.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
 btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
           String t = new String("http://myhttprequest");
           Request r = new Request(ma){
               protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                   editText.setText(result);
                   lv.setAdapter(result);
                   arrList.add(result);
                   arrAdapter.result();
               }
          };

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do I pretty simple.

1. Create an AsyncTask constructor that takes "delegate" as param
   1.1 In case the "delegate" is an Activity (it is in your case) just make sure it's hold in a WeakReference (to avoid memory leaks)
2. Do you thing with http
3. When you want to dispatch the callback, just use your "delegate" param (check for null - as it is a WeakReference).

Cheers!

Comment: I don't see how this fixes the problem with the code inside the `setOnClickListener`. I would really appreciate it if you could give me a short code example.